# Symfony unit test: how to set the request content type?

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, phpunit, content-type

When creating a unit test with phpunit and Symfony (extending `WebTestCase` class), I need to perform a request specifying the content-type.

So I have my client:

`$client->request('POST', '/my/route');`

but the request content-type defaults to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, how can I change it?

E.g. setting it to `application/json`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to add the content type in the fifth parameter:

```
$client->request('POST', '/my/route', [], [], ['CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json']);
```